# Export CSV file to local storage and open it using Ionic 4

Tags: typescript, ionic4, ionic-native

I am using Ionic 4 and I am trying to save export a string to CSV file, save it to dataDirectory (iOS) and then open this file.

```
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file/ngx';
import { DocumentViewer, DocumentViewerOptions } from '@ionic-native/document-viewer/ngx';

const options: DocumentViewerOptions = {
  title: 'My CSV'
};

const data = 'Foo,Bar';

constructor(private file: File,
            private documentViewer: DocumentViewer){}

exportCsvFile() {
  this.file.writeFile(this.file.dataDirectory,
  'test.csv',
  data,
  {replace: true})
  .then((res) => 
  this.documentViewer.viewDocument(this.file.dataDirectory + 'test.csv',
  'text/plain', options);)
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

When I debug, I can see that the file is created successfully. But the `documentViewer` doesn't display anything.